# yesodweb -example and extra tags in the output

Tags: haskell, yesod

Please, consider the following three pages that are very similar.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes,
         TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Yesod
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Text (Text)
import Text.Hamlet

data Example = Example

mkYesod "Example" [parseRoutes|
/ RootR GET
/page PageR GET
/page2 Page2R GET
|]

instance Yesod Example

getRootR :: GHandler sub Example RepHtml
getRootR = do
    defaultLayout [whamlet|
$doctype 5
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Tutorial, hello root
   <body>
     <h1 id="greeting">Hello root
|]


getPageR :: GHandler sub Example RepHtml
getPageR = defaultLayout $ do
    toWidgetHead [hamlet| <meta charset="utf-8"> |]
    setTitle "hello page"
    toWidget [hamlet|
<h1 id="greetings2">Hello page
|]

getPage2R :: GHandler sub Example RepHtml
getPage2R = defaultLayout $ do
    toWidget [hamlet|
$doctype 5
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Tutorial, hello page2
   <body>
     <h1 id="greeting">Hello page2
|]


main :: IO ()
main = warpDebug 3000 Example
```

RootR and page2 give the same output (I mean tags & structure) while "page" differ's a bit from the two. The outputs are, first "root" & "page2":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head><body><!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Tutorial, hello page2</title>
</head>
<body><h1 id="greeting">Hello page2</h1>
</body>
</html>
</body></html>
```

while the output of "page" is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>hello page</title><meta charset="utf-8"> </meta>
</head><body><h1 id="greetings2">Hello page</h1>
</body></html>
```

Why there are the extra  &  -tags in the "root" & "page2"? Should I add something into the code or take something away?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default-layout` function already contains `doctype` etc... and you are adding it again in root and page2.

Comment: Thank you! I took an example from the book and I didn't see it right away that the example used other function (widgetToPageContent). I'll add this to the yesod-wiki together with a "beginner's section" to see, if somebody else would like to share their "cases" when learning.

Comment: and there should have been hamletToRepHtml and not widgetToPageContent